# Hibernate with SqlServer performance drop on select

Tags: java, performance, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I have a performance issue with the following Hibernate TypedQuery:

```
select generatedAlias0 from MyClass1 as generatedAlias0
where generatedAlias0.class2.uid in (:param0, ..., :paramN)
```

Following the actual implementation this results in the following query:

```
select myclass1_.id, myclass1_.other, ... # 16 fields in total, no special big ones
from myschema.dbo.TblMyClass1 myclass1_ cross join myschema.dbo.TblMyClass2 myclass2_
where myclass1_.myclass2Id=myclass2.Id and (myclass2_.uid in('value1', ... 'valueN'))
```

Where N each time stands for 384 items.

When I execute this query in Toad it only takes about 150ms, but executed from code it takes almost a minute!

**Class mappings**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TblMyClass1", catalog = "myschema", schema = "dbo")
public class MyClass1 implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8208493383744288872L;

@Id
@Column(name = "Id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
protected Integer id;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "myclass2Id", referencedColumnName = "Id", nullable = false)
private MyClass2 class2 = null;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "myclass3Id", referencedColumnName = "Id", nullable = false)
private MyClass3 class3 = null;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "myClass4Id", referencedColumnName = "Id", nullable = false)
private MyClass4 myClass4;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "myClass5Uid", referencedColumnName = "UID", nullable = true)
private MyClass5 resultType;

@Column(name = "string2", nullable = true)
private String string2;

// other column fields and getters and setters ... 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TblMyClass2", schema = "myschema", catalog = "dbo")
public final class MyCLass2 implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4660579327140751989L;

@Id
@Column(name = "Id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
protected Integer id;

@Column(name = "uid", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
private String uid;

// ... other columns fields and getters and setters
}
```

I only provided the mappings for the two classes in the slow query, since the follow-up queries of hibernate which fill all other linked entities all perform very good.

Using Java VisualVm I find that the following method takes 99% of the time:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read()
```

I am running **SQL Server 2008** and using **sqljdbc4-2.0** and **hibernate4.2.1** with **spring3.2.9** (for transaction management)

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Looks like the problem is related to the mapping of your classes. Please provide how you map these classes and if you map another classes besides these.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have added the class mappings, but I myself can't really see what's wrong here, the other entities I did not provide since there are many of them and the queries to fill in those go very fast, all 380+ of them, it is only the first one whit the huge in(...) that doesn't perform. Thanks

Comment: Looks like when you load an instance of `MyClass1` it will also load an instance for `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` as well, and if each of these instances have mappings to more classes, then they would be loaded as well. Which means that in your query you only load data for a single class but when doing it on Hibernate you're loading data for your 380+ classes (probably).